# Ubuntu OpenCV not compiling

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile OpenCV 3.2 with contributions with the following commands:

```
1.
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/matteo/Desktop/Xilinx/OpenCV/source/opencv_contrib/modules/ /home/matteo/Desktop/Xilinx/OpenCV/source/opencv-3.2.0/
2.
make -j7 # runs 7 jobs in parallel
3.
sudo make install
```

Can you explain why I get

```
...
........
...........
........................
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- Downloading ...
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1043 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD cannot open file for write.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ../opencv_contrib/modules/dnn/cmake/OpenCVFindLibProtobuf.cmake:32 (ocv_download)
  ../opencv_contrib/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1047 (message):
  Failed to download .  Status=
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ../opencv_contrib/modules/dnn/cmake/OpenCVFindLibProtobuf.cmake:32 (ocv_download)
  ../opencv_contrib/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 . I already had OpenCV on the system: maybe I unistall it in the wrong way? I remember to compile OpenCV 3.2 with the same command used above.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem today updating from 3.1. I did a git pull on opencv_contrib. I wonder if maybe the problem is with that repo?

Comment: I can compile it just fine without the contrib modules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You must have matching versions of the opencv_contrib and the opencv itself.**

Under the opencv github, go to the [OpenCV releases](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases) and download the 3.2.0 (it should be the same in the master branch).

Now, go to https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases and download the 3.2.0. Then you will have both versions matching.

After that all the cmake commands found on the README.md at opencv_contrib master branch should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

I get the same error, that exact error, around the protobuf. There's another error on the xfeatures2d module, too, if your delete the dnn modules (so they don't get configured/built). My problem is, I need the "non-free" xfeatures2d module. :(

The problem appears to be in the opencv_contrib, in the DNN and xfeatures2d modules, but I'm not sure how to fix it. the call to ocv_download *seems* to be having empty inputs, even though the dnn and xfeatures2d cmake files are passing in arguments. I am not even a novice with cmake, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further.

I get this error on both Mac configuring for XCode and on Windows configuring for Visual Studio, using the latest version of cmake-gui, 3.8.0-rc3.

---

**EDIT:** I think I've found the issue, though. I opened an [issue in the opencv_contrib github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1100). There is a call to ocv_download in the dnn and xfeatures2d cmake files that uses FILENAME as the first parameter, but should be using PACKAGE instead. When I changed the parameters to PACKAGE, CMake successfully configured opencv with the opencv_contrib modules.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

You might not use the same version of opencv and opencv_contrib

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/`<version>`.zip
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/`<version>`.zip

like `master` or `3.2.0`

Comment: broken link - updated link for contrib is https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases (and https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases for noncontrib)

Answer (score 3):

**SHORT**

You need to have the same version in opencv and opencv_contrib (.../opencv_contrib/modules/... belongs to an independent repo).

Either the same release or the last commit in BOTH repositories.

Check which version you have and move the other. In your case, I guess you have to change the version of opencv_contrib, then move to the release with git or [download it from github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases).

`git checkout <number_opencv_version i.e. 3.2.0>`

**LONG**

I guess as Ken Lee, that you do not have the same version in the repositories.

As Matt referenced in the [opened issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1100), there is a problem with the call of ocv_download because the version is not the one that was used when opencv-3.1, therefore it fails because the parameter is not the expected one.

It happens to me when I was using opencv 3.1.0 and the last version of opencv_contrib. You could change the cmake files one by one, but it is easier to take the correct version in each repo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a right conflict in your build folder (may result from your previous `sudo make install`). I don't remember how I fixed it, but you can try recursively `chown` to both source and build folders (or `chmod` to 777).