# How to install opencv extra package

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, cmake

I need to use the cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() function for feature detection. I downloaded the `open_contrib` already. But I still get bunch of errors when using cmake to connect the extra modules with open_cv packages. Here are the error messages I got.

**Updates**
Now I changed the parameters FILENAME to PACKAGE from files

```
Files that use FILENAME instead of PACKAGE:
opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn/cmake/OpenCVFindLibProtobuf.cmake
opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/cmake/download_boostdesc.cmake
opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/cmake/download_vgg.cmake
```

and now I have two problems left, can anyone help?

```
    CMake Error at /home/darren/Desktop/OpenCV/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1043 (file):
  file DOWNLOAD cannot open file for write.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/darren/Desktop/opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn_modern/CMakeLists.txt:20 (ocv_download)


CMake Error at /home/darren/Desktop/OpenCV/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:1047 (message):
  Failed to download .  Status=
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/darren/Desktop/opencv_contrib-master/modules/dnn_modern/CMakeLists.txt:20 (ocv_download)
```

How can I remove this error and let me use that method.... (my opencv version is 3.2.0, and my the contri package is also 3.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me and re-downloading the extra modules fixed my problem. 
Did you try setting the `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` when running cmake? Something like `-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules` when running cmake.

Comment: @Darren Have you seen this SO post?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081022/ubuntu-opencv-not-compiling

Comment: Yes, I solved one error with the method he mentioned, now have two problems left